# How to get feature importance in Decision Tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset of reviews which has a class label of positive/negative. I am applying Decision Tree to that reviews dataset. Firstly, I am converting into a Bag of words. Here sorted_data['Text'] is reviews and final_counts is a sparse matrix.

I am splitting the data into train and test dataset.

```
X_tr, X_test, y_tr, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(sorted_data['Text'], labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# BOW
count_vect = CountVectorizer() 
count_vect.fit(X_tr.values)
final_counts = count_vect.transfrom(X_tr.values)
```

applying the Decision Tree algorithm as follows

```
# instantiate learning model k = optimal_k
# Applying the vectors of train data on the test data
optimal_lambda = 15
final_counts_x_test = count_vect.transform(X_test.values)
bow_reg_optimal = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=optimal_lambda,random_state=0)

# fitting the model
bow_reg_optimal.fit(final_counts, y_tr)

# predict the response
pred = bow_reg_optimal.predict(final_counts_x_test)

# evaluate accuracy
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, pred) * 100
print('\nThe accuracy of the Decision Tree for depth = %f is %f%%' % (optimal_lambda, acc))
```

**bow_reg_optimal** is a decision tree classifier. Could anyone tell how to get the **feature importance** using the decision tree classifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `feature_importances_` attribute, which will be defined once `fit()` is called. For example:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(1000,2)
y = np.random.randint(0, 5, 1000)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, y)
tree.feature_importances_
# array([ 0.51390759,  0.48609241])
```

Comment: `bow_reg_optimal.feature_importances_` and the output i am getting is `array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])`. Why I am getting all zeros?

Comment: The importances add up to 1. If that's the output you're getting, then the dominant features are probably not among the first three or last three, but somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jakevdp I am wondering why the top ones are not the dominant feature?